# Dynamic Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on a data trending worksheet that will have new data entered daily or weekly depending on the room.  I am currently trying to get the average of the data in let's call it A(X), and I want to format the cell such that

```
IF value(A(X))>=value(B(X)) && value(A(X)) < value(C(X))
    Fill Yellow
IF value(A(X))>=value(C(X))
    Fill Red
Else
    No Fill
```

Where B(X) contains a value that occasionally changes that warrants a warning (hence yellow) and C(X) contains a value that occasionally changes that warrants immediate action (hence red).

This data is being graphed as well.  Everything I've tried limits me to only selecting a single comparison cell for the entire rule, which would make me have to hardcode every additional line.  I've tried using OFFSET and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Can you include an example of rules you have tried? It sounds like you are almost there and will only need to change the absolute references to relative in your conditional formula.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with two different rules.
=$A1>=$B1
   Fill Yellow
=$A1>=$C1
   Fill Red

Answer (score 0):

you may change the `$A1>=$B1` to `=if(AND($A$1>=$B$1,$A$1<=$C$1),1,0)` in the formula for Yellow .. Then I think you're done. ( :